# Using generics in kotlin to respresent an Any

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following data class

```
data class LoginScreenState(
    val email: String,
    val username: String,
    val responseState: ResponseState<Any>?
)
```

I want the responseState to accept any Class or Unit. i.e. User, Registration, etc

In my following when expression

```
  when(val status = loginScreenState.value.responseState as ResponseState<Login>) {
            is ResponseState.Loading -> {
                /* TODO Showing loading spinner */
            }
            is ResponseState.Success -> {
                onLoginSuccess(status.data)
            }
            is ResponseState.Failure -> {
            }
            else -> Unit
        }
```

However, I get the following warning: `Unchecked cast: ResponseState<Any>? to ResponseState<Login>`

My ResponseState:

```
sealed interface ResponseState<out T> {
    object Loading : ResponseState<Nothing>
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : ResponseState<T>
    data class Failure(val error: Exception) : ResponseState<Nothing>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it helps, but it might help to redefine your `LoginScreenState` as:

```
data class LoginScreenState<T>(
    val email: String,
    val username: String,
    val responseState: ResponseState<T>?
)
```

Comment: Could be `out T` for better flexibility at use sites. OP will also need cast to a nullable. `when(val status = loginScreenState.value.responseState as ResponseState<Login>?)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Can you explain how that would be better to have out?

Comment: @ant2009, it adds flexibility. It would make it so LoginScreenState can be upcast to one that holds a supertype.